# Bootstrap Progressbar not visible on top of Navigation Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the usual bootstrap navigation menu and a progressbar on top of it using `fixed` positon property. But the progress bar isn't visible on top of navigation menu. I have tried using `z-index` but it wasn't of any use.

The code is like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
...
...
</div>
<div class="container" id="sim-progress">
...
...
</div>
```

I have added some custom css to the progress bar. I have demonstrated the problem in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psibi/NKy7W/3/). I want to show the progress bar on top of the navigation menu. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: It's there but hidden behind the navbar. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/NKy7W/5/

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to show it on top of the navigation bar.

Comment: So move it **into** the navbar and position it accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/NKy7W/6/

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you put that solution as an answer, I will accept that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is necessary is to put the progress bar **into** the nabvar div and position it as required.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/NKy7W/6/) (basic)

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="container" id="sim-progress">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active sim-pro">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%"><span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```